# onKeyEvent handling OK button

Tags: roku, brightscript

Some interesting behavior. When I use

```
else if key = "OK" and m.streambutton.hasFocus()
    print("OK BUTTON WORKING")
    handled = true
```

nothing prints to the console.

If I change "OK" to any other button such as "play" when I press that button while the button is highlighted the print handles correctly. For example:

```
else if key = "play" and m.streambutton.hasFocus()
    print("OK BUTTON WORKING")
    handled = true
```

Here is my whole function:

```
function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean
    handled = false
    m.keys = m.top.findNode("streamcodekeyboard")
    m.streambutton = m.top.findNode("streamcodeenter")

    if press
        if key = "down" and not m.keys.hasFocus()
            m.keys.setFocus(true)
            handled = true
        else if key = "up" and not m.keys.hasFocus()
            m.keys.setFocus(true)
            handled = true
        else if key = "right" and not m.streambutton.hasFocus()
            m.streambutton.setFocus(true)
            handled = true
        else if key = "OK" and m.streambutton.hasFocus()
            print("OK BUTTON WORKING")
            handled = true
        end if
    end if

    return handled
end function
```

Is there something unique about the "OK" button I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

From the code, it seems "*m.streambutton*" is a button that has the focus right now. in this case *"OK"* button selection will be captured by "*m.streambutton*" and as you may not be having the code to handle this. There is "*buttonSelected*" filed for button that can be observed to handle the button selection i.e. "*OK*" button press. To get this work, after creating button, add observer for "*buttonSelected*" field in the code--

```
m.streambutton.observeField("buttonSelected", "streamBUttonSelected")
```

"*streamButtonSelected*" is a function that you have to write to handle the button selection--

```
function streamButtonSelected()
    print "stream button selected. write your code to handle button selection"
end function
```